# Add buttons on outlook mail box

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I want to implement buttons or hyperlinks in outlook email. Based on the button / link click, value should update in database using .net
 The scenario is to implement Leave Management Process.When the user has any leave request ,a mail will be send to the Approver, then the Approver opens the site to approve or reject it. But rather than opening the site ,I want to add buttons or links in outlook email itself , so that Approver can click on it to approve /reject and it should update the database accordingly.

I am using ASP.Net 4.5 and C#. How could I implement this logic in  ASP.net? Pls provide any idea or any links.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the initial description you need to develop an Outlook add-in where you can customize the Outlook UI. Because the Outlook object model doesn't provide any event for handling hyperlinks clicks.

> I am using ASP.Net 4.5 and C#. How could I implement this logic in ASP.net?

Take a look at the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article which states the following:

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

You may consider using EWS on the server-side. Or just BCL classes.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for your comments. I can write BCL Classes . But how will I get the response from outlook  to the application? If not buttons, can I provide some links that specifies the type of action, Approve or Reject?